# LNMP installer package

Tags: mysql, php, centos, nginx

I am trying to find a LNMP installer that does everything at once. Do you guys know any?
I also want PHP to run with fast CGI.This will be running on my rackspace server with centOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you averse to installing via `yum`? If you install via a "one-click" installer, you'll be missing out on all of the regular security and version updates offered by the CentOS crew. Really, it's trivially easy to install things via yum.

Since nginx is not available through the default CentOS repo, you'll need to add the EPEL repo:

```
$ su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm'
$ yum update
```

Then:

```
yum install nginx php-cli php make automake gcc gcc-c++ spawn-fcgi wget mysql-server
chkconfig --add nginx
chkconfig --level 35 nginx on
service nginx start
```

(source: the [Linode Library](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/php-fastcgi/centos-5), more info available there)

Comment: yes, I did that actually... but then now it seems that I am stuck with phpMyAdmin not running and it's stressing me out as no one can seem to help me

Comment: then you'll have to configure fast-cgi

Comment: Honestly, without more information, there's not much I can say. If you're able, I'd just recommend trashing the VPS and starting over with a clean OS image. You'll be able to put into practice the things you've learned so far and you'll have a much better change of things going well.

Comment: I was actually going to do that... and follow your suggestions

Comment: Great - good luck!

Comment: But I need a great tutorial on how to do all that... I might change from centOS to ubuntu as they have better support

Comment: Check out the article I linked to - full details are there.

Comment: install "make automake gcc gcc-c++" is very strange

Comment: @EEAA: while I run command `yum install nginx php-cli php make automake gcc gcc-c++ spawn-fcgi wget mysql-server`. It is taking lot of time and installing lot of things as well not sure what is going on

Comment: Then you should research what the command is for. It is dangerous to blindly copy/paste commands and run them without knowing what they are going to do.

Answer (score 0):

why php-cgi ? why not php-fpm ? If you need an all in one installer which is menu based for CentOS/RHEL check out http://centminmod.com/